# How to use mongo database queries?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using MongoDb for my c sharp project instead of mysql, now i want  to use query like select * from student Where (name is null or name='XXX') and (sno is null or sno=10), how can i build this query in mongodb.

thanks,
@dinnu.

Comment: Have you problems in building the MongoDB JSON string for the query or do you not know how to do it with a c# client?

Comment: i am not knowing how to do with a c# client

Comment: I hate to be the anal one here but isn't this just a Google search away from being answered. SO shouldn't be used for "first hit on google" kind of questions.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
var mongoServer = MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost?safe=true");
var mongoDatabase = mongoServer.GetDatabase("test");
var mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<TModel>("Test");

var cursor = mongoCollection.Find(Query.And(
    Query.Or(
        Query.EQ("Name", "xxx"),
        Query.EQ("Name", null)), 
    Query.Or(
        Query.EQ("sno", 10)),
        Query.EQ("sno", null)));
```

Where `TModel` is the type of the class you want to deserialize from the db. Now you can use cursor to iterate the results of that query, for example:

```
var someModel = cursor.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: the above query not working for me...it gives wrong output@mnemosym

Comment: if name takes null, the query getting all table collection

Comment: I write query below like this 'var query = Query.And(Query.Or( Query.EQ("35", msg), Query.EQ("35",string.Empty)), Query.Or(Query.EQ("44", msg1), Query.EQ("44", int.MinValue)));' var result=Tablename.Find(query);@mnemosyn

Comment: Are your field names really numbers like "44"? The first param of the `EQ` method is the name of the field you want to check against.

Comment: yeah..fields names are numbers like 44, 100 etc...in the above query i send 35 field anme value through "msg" string.@mnemoyn

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Fluent Mongo (https://github.com/craiggwilson/fluent-mongo).  It adds Linq on top of the official 10gen driver.  Thus far I have found using it to be a good experience.  It is available via the Nuget or the GitHub.